# Identify LEGO set with caped red minifigure

Tags: set-identification, minifigures

[image]

Hi just wondered if someone can help identify a set for us? The best clue I have is a red minifigure with a red cape, red full face helmet & black head (no face). I also have an orange square with a face on it which may go with this figure. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 13):

These items are from different sets.

Let's begin with the most obvious - minifigure. It is a Royal Guard from Star Wars and there are couple of versions of them. Yours seems to be with arms and hands in Dark Red. Yet, there are still two version of them (depends on the type of cape you got):

[Royal Guard with Dark Red Arms and Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0521) was part of [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=sw0521&in=S) in 2014-2015.

Or, it can be [Royal Guard with Dark Red Arms and Hands (Spongy Cape)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0521b) that was part of another [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=sw0521b&in=S) in 2016 and 2019.

Next comes a tile. Your picture is tiny, however I think I have identified it correctly as [Tile 1 x 1 with Groove with Face with Narrowed Eyes, One Eyebrow Raised and Small Frown (Kryptomite) Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3070bpb109) in Orange. It was available in [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3070bpb109&colorID=4&in=A) (non Star Wars).

It is impossible to identify correctly which wedge plate version you got in your picture. It is either [Wedge, Plate 4 x 9 without Stud Notches](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2413#T=C) which appeared in [58 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2413&colorID=1&in=A) in White color, or [Wedge, Plate 4 x 9 with Stud Notches](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14181#T=C) that was part of [14 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=14181&colorID=1&in=A) in White.

Comment: Wow thanks so much!! That was incredible!!!

Comment: @Tess Welcome to Bricks.SE. If this answers your question site guidelines suggest you click the checkbox by the answer to "accept" it.